# how to do Feedback form in gmail signature?

Tags: php, mysql, gmail

I created a feedback system in my `gmail signature`, I put smiley's images as links(`Excellent,Good,average,Bad`) , I want to get feedback and email Id  from my customers when they click one of the `smiley's` and `store` in Database.
I am getting feedback Value in `Database` and How can i get respective Email Id?
Please help me . Thanks  in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm fairly sure (correct me if I'm wrong) that you cannot just get the email address of the user that is receiving the message when they click on it, unless you specifically add that as a GET parameter to the links before you send it or you create a confirmation page on your server.

In my example below I have created an email 'confirmation' page which will ask for the users email before placing it in the database. Obviously the data should only be entered into the database through a prepared statement.

**Example Email footer:**

> Rate my service!
>
> Excellent - Good - Average - Bad

Excellent would link to your `script.php?rating=excellent` and etc. for the other 3 ratings.

**Example script.php:**

```
<?php if (!isset($_GET['email'])): // The user has not entered their email in the form. ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Please enter your Email address</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="/script.php" method="GET">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="john@example.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="rating" value="<?=$_GET['rating']?>">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php exit(); // Don't execute the switch below. ?>
<?php endif;

switch($_GET['rating']) { // Pick what to do for each rating.
    case 'excellent':
        // Add your database code here for 'excellent' ratings...
        break;
    case 'good':
        // Add your database code here for 'good' ratings...
        break;
    case 'average':
        // Add your database code here for 'average' ratings...
        break;
    case 'bad':
        // Add your database code here for 'bad' ratings...
        break;
}
```

Hope this helps!